# Present 2 Slide Shows Simultaneously

Tags: powerpoint

I have two PowerPoint presentations that are identical but one is in English and one is in Spanish. They Are in two presentations So I present them separately or simultaneously and it does not work well to try to cram the content into one presentation wits slides in both languages. I would like to be able to connect my pc to two displays with one presentation on each screen. Then when I click or enter to advance the content on one presentation the other follows automatically. I have used VBA to automate Excel but never with PowerPoint.

how I envision this working is that I would run the code and it would ask for the 2 presentations and launch them in separate windows that can be positioned on each screen. when the enter key is pressed or the mouse button is clicked it would advance the content then activate the other presentation advance the content then reactivate the first presentation. If there is no more content to advance on the slide it would then advance the slide itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that works with PowerPoint.  If there are multiple displays, PowerPoint expects to control them all, giving presenters notes on the second screen.  You may need to use a second laptop.

Comment: @Tim Roberts This can be done by 1) select slide show tab. 2) select set up slide show. 3) change show type from presented by speaker to browsed by individual. 4) select ok and do this same thing in the second presentation. This will allow them to be presented in individual windows that can be moved to separate monitors. The down side to this is that to advance the slides you have to select a window then click or enter to advance the ontent/slide. Then select the second presentation and click or enter to advance the content/slide. It is fairly easy to get the slides out of sync.

Comment: Adding to JBoltz's idea, you could also set the slide width to be twice the width of a single monitor and make a single presentation that duplicates each slide, one language on the left, the same slide but the other language on the right. You won't be able to run the presentation window maximized, but drag the borders of the window to be as large as possible, spanning across both monitors. You'll have a title bar across the top during your presentation, and my initial test has black bars down each side, which could be mitigated by making the slide even wider.